# Inverse function simple question

Tags: education

[image: Function-1]

Please explain question no. c in detail

Comment: Please show us what you tried and what your answers at (a) and (b) are.

Comment: http://i.imgur.com/kz8G91a.jpg

Comment: Question (c) asks you to show that the graph of $f^{-1}$ and the graph of $f$ are symmetric with respect to the line $y=x$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**HINT :** If you look at the inverse graph of a function it is nothing but the reflection of the point $(x,f(x))$ along the line $y=x$. So intuitively $f(f^{-1}(x))$ resembles taking the reflection twice. Which brings you back to the original point.